# decltype and member function (not pointer) type

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, decltype, visual-c++-2012

```
struct C
{
    int Foo(int i) { return i; }

    typedef decltype(C::Foo) type;
};
```

Since there is no such type as a member function type (there isn't, is there?), I expect `C::type` to be `int (int)`.

But the following won't compile using the Visual C++ 2012 RC:

```
std::function<C::type> f;
```

So what type is `decltype(C::Foo)`?

Comment: When I need ask "what type is <expression>", I use something like this to coax the compiler to print the type for me `struct{}_ = <expression>;`. Usually works well with GCC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code is ill-formed:  there are only a few ways that a member function name (e.g. `C::Foo`) can be used, and this is not one of them (the complete list of valid uses can be found in the C++ language standard, see C++11 §5.1.1/12).

In the context of your example, the only thing you can really do is take the address of the member function, `&C::Foo`, to form a pointer to the member function, of type `int (C::*)(int)`.

Since the code is ill-formed, the compiler should reject it.  Further, it yields inconsistent results depending on how `C::Foo` is used; we'll look at the inconsistency below.

Please report a bug on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio).  Alternatively, let me know and I am happy to report the issue.

---

If you have a type but you don't know what the type is, you can find out the name of the type by using it in a way that causes the compiler to emit an error.  For example, declare a class template and never define it:

```
template <typename T>
struct tell_me_the_type;
```

Then later, you can instantiate this template with the type in which you are interested:

```
tell_me_the_type<decltype(C::Foo)> x;
```

Since `tell_me_the_type` hasn't been defined, the definition of `x` is invalid.  The compiler *should* include the type `T` in the error it emits.  Visual C++ 2012 RC reports:

```
error C2079: 'x' uses undefined struct 'tell_me_the_type_name<T>'
with
[
    T=int (int)
]
```

The compiler thinks that `C::Foo` is of type `int (int)`.  If that is the case, then the compiler should accept the following code:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_the_type_right;

template <>
struct is_the_type_right<int(int)> { };

is_the_type_right<decltype(C::Foo)> x;
```

The compiler does not accept this code.  It reports the following error:

```
error C2079: 'x' uses undefined struct 'is_the_type_right<T>'
with
[
    T=int (int)
]
```

So, `C::Foo` both is of type `int (int)` and is not of type `int (int)`, which violates the [principle of noncontradiction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_noncontradiction). :-)

Comment: Brilliant way to reveal the alleged type.  Do you ever deliver bug reports to the compiler team in person?

Comment: @James thx. Can you report this please? I'm not sure how to phrase this issue.

Comment: Actually I believe the first part is wrong. AFAIK, `decltype(expr)` does not evaluate the expression, and that means that it falls in the last category: *if that id-expression denotes a non-static data member and it appears in an unevaluated operand.*

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas:  C++11 §5.1.1/10, cited in the answer, states:  "An _id-expression_ that denotes a non-static data member or non-static member function of a class can only be used...," followed by a list of permitted uses.  Use as an operand of `decltype` is not in the list.

Comment: On the second part, I have seen that behavior in C++03 in different compilers, I will try to locate a proper quote from the standard, but I believe that the type of the expression `C::Foo` **is** `int (int)` (and this is some weird behavior in the language), I run this experiment some time ago: `typedef int f_t(int); struct test { f_t foo; }; int test::foo(int) { return 0; }` which compiles fine in different compilers. I seem to recall that the standard actually supports this syntax...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas:  `C::foo` does not denote _a non-static data member,_ though.  It denotes a nonstatic member function.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: You are right, I misread the item. The quote regarding the use of `typedef` would be 8.3.5/10

Comment: @BenVoigt:  By e-mail, occasionally.  I don't want to irritate them _too_ much.  :-)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas:  I saw that while I was researching this answer... that caught me by surprise.  I've never seen that "feature" used :-)

Comment: @Nubcase:  Sure, I'm happy to report the issue.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: Imagine how I felt when I did see that in production code! I thought that the compiler was incorrectly accepting that code, until I found that quote...

Answer (score 1):

> So what type is `decltype(C::Foo)`?

It's no type, since using just `C::Foo` is ill-formed.