# Is there any way to deduce template parameters from base class function parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, arguments

I try to create a convenient wrapper for callback structures.

```
class CallbackFilterProducts {
public:
    virtual ~CallbackFilterProducts() {}

    virtual void onFinish(const optional<Page>& page,
                          const vector<Product>& products) = 0;
};


template <typename T, typename... Args>
struct Callback : T {
Callback() {}

void onFinish(Args&&... args) override
{
    _promise.set_value(make_tuple(forward<Args>(args)...));
}

auto&& promise() { return _promise; }

private:
    promise<
        tuple<remove_const_t<remove_reference_t<Args>>...>> _promise;
};
```

As for now, I have to use it like:

```
auto callback = make_shared<
    Callback<CallbackFilterProducts, const optional<Page>&,
             const vector<Product>&>>();
auto future = callback->promise().get_future();
```

Is there any way to deduce `Args` from `CallbackFilterProducts::onFinish` function and use it like:

```
auto callback = make_shared<Callback<CallbackFilterProducts>();
```

Comment: That usage does not look convenient at all. Not even with the arguments deduced. You have dynamic memory allocations, virtual function calls, futures and promises... Are you sure this is how you want to make callbacks?

Comment: The library I'm working with communicates only through callbacks mechanism. So, I have to create many callbacks of the same type and put a callback into a callback, into a callback... It's just an attempt to work out a different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If onFinish is neither overloaded nor templated (as it should be, being virtual), you may simply write (not tested):

```
template <typename T, typename Sig = decltype(&T::onFinish)>
struct Callback {};

template <typename T, typename... Args>
struct Callback<T,void(T::*)(Args...)> : T {
  Callback() {}

  void onFinish(Args... args) override;
};
```

Comment: @anatol, beware there was a copy-paste-typo I fixed just after your comment (the extra && shouldn't have been there); moreover, keep in mind this will explode if later on you add an onFinish overload ...

Comment: Why not simply `template <typename T, typename Sig = decltype(T::onFinish)>`?

Comment: @Aconcagua I don't think that's legal (in fact, my clang complains), what compiler are you using ? IIRC vc++ allows that as a non-standard extension ...

Comment: @Aconcagua maybe it's a gcc extension then; see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354841/decltype-and-member-function-not-pointer-type) and similar ...

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes. Interesting, but you seem to be right... On the other hand, GCC still compiles if dropping `std::remove_pointer` solely, but leaving the address-of operator; this somehow makes sense, though, as `void(T::*)(Args...)`, with which you instanciate, is a pointer type, too, isn't it?

Comment: @Aconcagua yep, that's correct, the remove_ptr is redundant, edited ...